# Else if not working in javascript

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I'm working with an upload script,these lines of codes are not working.Here 'else if' condition doesn't works.It does not showing txt_file.png as a preview of file if a text file uploaded.

```
if (!file.type.match(/ image.*/)) {
    if (file.type.match(/ *.avi/)){
        myDropzone.emit("thumbnail", file, "images1/video_icon.png");
    } else if  (file.type.match(/ *.txt/)){
        myDropzone.emit("thumbnail", file, "images1/text_icon.png");
    }
    ....
}
```

Am i doing anything wrong ?Pls help me.Thank you..

Comment: what is not working exactly?

Comment: Define "not working".

Comment: do you have any error in the chrome's console?

Comment: @sabotero I'm wondering why exactly chrome lol

Comment: else if condition doesn't works.It does not showing txt_file.png as preview of file if a text file uploaded.

Comment: How does your "file.type" looks like if it's a txt file?

Answer (score 4):

Regular expressions are not correct. Change

```
/ *.txt/
```

to

```
/.*\.txt/
```

or event better `/.*\.txt$/`.

Character `*` has a special meaning in regular expressions. So it has to be escaped if you use it like you did (however it would not work as expected anyway, because it would not match file extensions).

The same with `*.avi`. Also you would probably want to use [`test`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) for this task.

More information here: [Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

Comment: Oopz this is also not working.. :( ..In my previous code it shows video_icon if a .avi file uploaded but not showing text file icon  if a text file uploaded..

Comment: Hm, so the problem somewhere else. The code should work. http://jsfiddle.net/VP77t/ Make sure `file.type` is accurate.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to use the .search() function on a string and not the .match() because you don't care about a matching result you only need a boolean condition.

```
if (file.type.search(/\.avi/) !== -1){
    myDropzone.emit("thumbnail", file, "images1/video_icon.png");
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search